# std::vector of known sequences

Tags: c++, vector

I'm trying to learn C++ by doing everything "the C++ way".  I'm writing a program where I have all of these known values (at compile time).  Here is my problem:

In my constructor I want to check to see if a passed value(an int) is one of 2,4,8,16 or 32 and throw an error elsewise.  I've though about:

1. making a C style array or ints
2. creating a vector before by hand and interating through it to check
3. making a list?  I've never used lists before though.

What I really want to do is make a const vector in a separate header file, this doesn't seem possible though.

What is the most elegant way to do this check?

Also, similarly is there any way to make a vector with a set number of known values (at compile time) in a header?  If I can do `const std::string a_str("a string");` I don't see why I can't use a similar technique for vectors.

Comment: "I don't see why I can't use a similar technique for vectors."

Initialization lists for classes.  I believe this is a planned "c++0x" feature.  Not in the standard yet...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What's wrong with:

```
if (!(n == 2 || n == 4 || n == 8 || n == 16 || n == 32))
{
    // no!
}
```

If you want the "C++ way", a static array should do, with `find`:

```
template <typename T, size_t N>
T* endof(T (&pArray)[N])
{
    return &pArray[0] + N;
}

static const int OkNumbers[] = {2, 4, 8, 16, 32};
static const int* OkNumbersEnd = endof(OkNumbers);
if (std::find(OkNumbers, OkNumbersEnd, n) == OkNumbersEnd)
{
    // no!
}
```

Modifying this list is simple, and I'm guessing the compiler *may* optimize this to my previous answer.

Comment: he wants to do it "the C++ way"

Comment: This isn't C++ code? Anyone who set up a list just to check for a few numbers is doing too much work, I think.

Comment: I didn't say it isn't C++, he said he wants to do it "the C++ way" what ever that's supposed to mean. I agree it is too much work but he might just be doing it for an exercise

Comment: Instead of the `endof` method, try this: `OkNumbersEnd = OkNumbers + sizeof(OkNumbers) / (OkNumbers[0]);` which can be calculated at compile time and no need for a template.

Comment: Your code is more verbose and mine is compile time as well. It's not like templates are a bad thing.

Comment: Not to mention yours can only be turned into a macro, which is less preferable to a function.

Answer (score 6):

It's a bit of a trick, but I believe this works:

```
if (n & (n-1) != 0)
{
   // not a power of two
}
```

Comment: I figured he would only want the 5 numbers listed in the OP. Perhaps a range check would make it appropriate.

Comment: `0 == 0x0000` is not a power of two. `(0-1) == -1 == 0xffff`, and `0x0000 & 0xffff == 0x0000 == 0` which is **not** `!= 0`. So something in your logic is flawed.

Comment: hhafez: Well, adding a `(n > 32)` comparison is trivial.

Comment: If you want to exclude 64 and greater (and 1) you can easily check for those explicitly. `if(n & (n - 1) && n >= 2 && n <= 32)` is more succinct (and maintainable - what if we later want to allow 64, 128, 256, etc.?) than the alternative of checking all values explicitly. +1

Comment: @ndim - It's not a perfect check, but it's probably more efficient (and easier to maintain) than testing against each specific value.

Comment: I guess it only works for `n>=1`, or if counting `0` as a power of two does not matter.

Answer (score 2):

If we're talking about bit twiddling sillyness, here's my try:

```
if ((n & 0x3E) != n || (n & n - 1) != 0)
  throw std::runtime_error("not a power of two less than or equal to 32");
```

Bit twiddling sillyness is VERY C/C++, but only "elegant" if by elegant you mean "as few processor cycles as absolutely possible and in as terse a syntax as possible".  Use a dictionary lookup or explicit check (such as std::find in GMan's answer), otherwise.

Readability is almost always preferrable to this kind of wackyness.

Answer (score 1):

If you are really looking for doing it with a vector and want nice assignment operations have a look at boost::assign.

But you just really don't want to do it with a vector ;)

Edit: I just saw your "at compile time". Consider why this can't be done: `std::vector` isn't a built in type. To have a mechanism to use somekind of smart assignment like that would require to built in support for it for the whole language and every user-defined type. Even if you don't need core language support and can do it with Templates this wouldn't be consistent with the overall style of the STL.

Comment: std::string is not a built-in type, and the code you gave in the question doesn't create a string at compile time. It creates a string at runtime and initializes it with a C-style string literal. std::string just happens to have that nice way of initialising it, which vector doesn't. C++0x will introduce initializer lists, which will let you do `std::vector<int> v = {1, 2, 3};` or `std::vector<std::string> v2 = {"1", "2", "3"};`

Comment: No. The constructor you are reffering to takes const char* as an argument. This pointer is taken from the string literal "a string". String literals are "built-in".

Comment: Yes, but when devin says "is string a built-in type", the answer must be "no". By "string", he either means "std::string" (which is not a built-in type), or else he means "string literal" (which is not a type at all). Everywhere in my above comment where I say "string" I mean "std::string", except where I say "C-style string literal".

Answer (score 0):

Use a normal C array, my C is rusty but here goes

```
int array[] = {2,4,8,16,32};

/* now loop over the array and check */

for( i = 0; i< size_of_array ; i++) {
  if (array[i] == input_int) 
  /* you get the idea ..... */
```

Answer (score 0):

This might not fit the context of what you're trying to do, but you can use an enum.

Since this is compile time knowledge, I'll assume that these passed values are important at compile time.  Using an enum, callers aren't trying to figure out what magic number to pass into your function.

```
typedef enum 
{
  Value1 = 2,
  Value2 = 4,
  Value4 = 8,
  Value5 = 16,
  Value6 = 32

} MyMagicType;

void MyFunction(MyMagicType theType)
{
...
}
```

The compiler will then enforce the value to be one of the above (well, unless you cast it, but that is a different matter) and throw an error should it not be one of the defined values.